# Como faço para enviar o body em uma requisição (POST), no axios?

Tags: request, axios

```html
    axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: 'https://backend.tangotechapp.com/REST/getTokenRequest',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' },

    }).then(
      response => {

        console.log(response.data);

      }
    ).catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

Comment: Mas mostra algum erro?

Comment: Ele não retorna o token, o body está sendo enviado vazio.

Comment: O tipo da requisição é 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'

Answer (score 1):

Você pode simplesmente adicionar "data" ao objeto. Nesse campo você pode adicionar aquilo que você deseja enviar junto a requisição.
Exemplo:

```
axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: '/user/12345',
  data: {
    nome: 'Victor',
    sobrenome: 'Nogueira'
  }
});
```

Dê uma lida na documentação disponível no GitHub que pode ser util: https://github.com/axios/axios

Comment: Já tentei fazer isso, mas parece que não vai nada no body, o token retorna vazio.

Comment: João da uma olhada aí na sua Api, pq a chamada está correta, é pra funcionar normalmente!

Comment: @JoãoFilipe, O código que acima está certo, então o erro provavelmente está em sua api, mas sem o código é difícil dizer.